# Webpack with Vue CLI doesn't work after dependency update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

This is my `package.json`

```
{
"name": "x",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "index.js",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode=development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production"
},
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.0",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.0",
    "html-webpack-inline-source-plugin": "0.0.10",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "remove-files-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.3",
    "sass": "^1.20.3",
    "sass-loader": "^11.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-loader": "^15.7.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^5.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
}
```

}

And this is my webpack.config.js

```
    const HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin = require('html-webpack-inline-source-plugin');
const RemovePlugin = require('remove-files-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = (env, argv) => ({
    // This is necessary because Figma's 'eval' works differently than normal eval
    devtool: argv.mode === 'production' ? false : 'inline-source-map',

    entry: {
        ui: './src/ui.js', // The entry point for your UI code
        code: './src/code.js' // The entry point for your plugin code
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            // Converts TypeScript code to JavaScript
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/]
                }
            },

            // Enables including CSS by doing "import './file.css'" in your TypeScript code
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }] },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            implementation: require('sass')
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader'
            },
            // Allows you to use "<%= require('./file.svg') %>" in your HTML code to get a data URI
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|webp|svg)$/, loader: [{ loader: 'url-loader' }] }
        ]
    },

    // Webpack tries these extensions for you if you omit the extension like "import './file'"
    resolve: { extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.jsx', '.js'] },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist') // Compile into a folder called "dist"
    },

    // Tells Webpack to generate "ui.html" and to inline "ui.ts" into it
    plugins:
        argv.mode === 'production'
            ? [
                    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
                    new RemovePlugin({
                        after: { include: ['dist/ui.js'] }
                    }),
                    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                        template: './src/ui.html',
                        filename: 'ui.html',
                        inlineSource: '.(js|css|scss)$',
                        chunks: ['ui']
                    }),
                    new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin()
              ]
            : [
                    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
                    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                        template: './src/ui.html',
                        filename: 'ui.html',
                        inlineSource: '.(js|css|scss)$',
                        chunks: ['ui']
                    }),
                    new HtmlWebpackInlineSourcePlugin()
              ]
});
```

Error

```
[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[4] should be one of these:
   ["..." | object { compiler?, dependency?, descriptionData?, enforce?, exclude?, generator?, include?, issuer?, issuerLayer?, layer?, loader?, mimetype?, oneOf?, options?, parser?, realResource?, resolve?, resource?, resourceFragment?, resourceQuery?, rules?, sideEffects?, test?, type?, use? }, ...]
   -> A rule.
   Details:
    * configuration.module.rules[4].loader should be a non-empty string.
      -> A loader request.
```

After updating dependencies everything blew up, I am getting error message which I don't understand as loader is a string. My knowledge about webpack is very limited. Can somebody please help?

Comment: So are you serious asking question with "after dependency update" in the title and not telling which dependencies exactly did you updated?

Comment: This is why I posted my package.json. I have run yarn upgrade --latest

Comment: If the error is "after dependency update" you need to post versions **before** and **after** - not just after...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`{ test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|webp|svg)$/, loader: [{ loader: 'url-loader' }] }`
to

`{ test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|webp|svg)$/, use: [{ loader: 'url-loader' }] }`

And you need to do that everywhere (obviously):

`{ test: /\.css$/, loader: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }] },`

-->

`{ test: /\.css$/, use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }] },`

Comment: Now I see a new error `* configuration.module.rules[1].loader should be a non-empty string.`

Comment: These changes helped!